# Is every continuously differentiable function also absolutely continuous?

Tags: measure-theory, continuity, lebesgue-integral

**Context:** I have been struggling a little bit understanding the concepts of absolute continuity and its relation to the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. The main issue is that I find the definition of absolute continuity a bit unintuitive. Thus, I have been trying to figure out what are conditions which imply that a function $f$ is absolutely continuous.

**Question:** A natural question to me is "whether all continuously differentiable functions on compact intervals are absolutely continuous?"

**My answer:** This is true. Let $f:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be continuously differentiable. Then its derivative $f'$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and hence Riemann integrable. Therefore, by the Second Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, we conclude that for every $x\in[a,b]$
$$ \int_a^x f'(y)dy = f(x)-f(a)$$
Thus we see that $f$ is an indefinite integral. It follows (Theorem 5.14 in Royden) that $f$ is absolutely continuous.

If the above "trivial" argument is correct, then I am still a bit unsatisfied since I relied on Riemann integration result rather than Lebesgue integration results (as covered in Chapter 5 of Royden).

**Question 2:** Is there an argument which leverages Lebesgue integration theory directly without reference to the FTC for Riemann integral? I am asking because the crux of my argument does not rely on the results from Royden (except for the final conclusion).

My question might be trivial but since I am self-studying these concepts I want to make sure that I organize them properly in my mind.

**My level:** Self-studying first part of Royden (1988) (i.e., Chapters 1-6).

Comment: If it's continuously differentiable then it's continuous. All continuous functions are absolutely continuous on a compact set.

Comment: @CyclotomicField Isn't Cantor-Lebesgue function an example of a function that is continuous on a compact interval and which is not absolutely continuous?

Comment: You're right. I'm confusing uniformly continuous with absolutely continuous. Continuously differentiable function are absolutely continuous on a compact interval.

Comment: Thanks! Is then my argument as described in the question correct?

Comment: "If the above "trivial" argument is correct" Yes, it is. And note that Riemann and Lebesgue integral coincide on continuous functions over compact intervals. You can prove the claim also directly with the original definition of absolute continuity.

Comment: @amsmath How could I prove this directly? Any hint?

Comment: You can prove that it satisfies the definition of absolute continuity by using the Mean Value Theorem plus the fact that the derivative is bounded (since it is continuous on a closed interval).  If you are worried that it all seems too easy is because you have chosen a much too strong hypothesis.

Comment: @Mdoc $$\sum_k|f(y_k)-f(x_k)|\le\sum_k(\max_{x\in [a,b]}|f'(x)|)\cdot(y_k-x_k) = (\max_{x\in [a,b]}|f'(x)|)\cdot\sum_k(y_k-x_k).$$

Comment: @amsmath Thank you so much!

Comment: With zero additional work this gets you that every Lipschitz function is absolutely continuous.

Comment: @NateEldredge That's a good point! I know that result (its an easy exercise in Royden), but somehow I did not see that a similar argument works here. It should have been obvious to me as I knew that every continuously differentiable function is locally Lipschitz. Just did not make the connection.